# Java Ordered Map

Tags: java, collections

Is there an object in Java that acts like a Map for storing and accessing key/value pairs, but can return an ordered list of keys and an ordered list of values, such that the key and value lists are in the same order?

So as explanation-by-code, I'm looking for something that behaves like my fictitious OrderedMap:

```
OrderedMap<Integer, String> om = new OrderedMap<>();
om.put(0, "Zero");
om.put(7, "Seven");

String o = om.get(7); // o is "Seven"
List<Integer> keys = om.getKeys();
List<String> values = om.getValues();

for(int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++)
{
    Integer key = keys.get(i);
    String value = values.get(i);
    Assert(om.get(key) == value);
}
```

Comment: [SortedMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Comment: If all you're wanting to do is iterating through both at the same time, then Map.entrySet() will let you do that on any map. The LinkedHashMap has a well defined order, but for any Map the entry set reflects the key/value pairs.

Comment: This code is not a good example as any Map implementation will behave as your sample code. sorted, ordered or not.

Comment: Peter Lawrey: Could you expand upon that? The Map interface returns keys and values as a Set and Collection, respectively. Order is not guaranteed in either of these, so it doesn't seem sensible to say that every Map implementation will behave as in my example code.

Comment: In the Sun JDK implementation, the sets returned by getKeys and getValues() sets are backed by the entrySet() in the map, so will have the same iteration order, which is what your sample tests.

Comment: Well that's interesting, I never noticed that. Still, call me crazy, but I prefer not to make assumptions about implementation that aren't explicitly verified by the interface. I've been burned too many times doing that in the past.

Comment: This should be named Java Sorted Map, as Ordered Map is something different - see `LinkedHashMap`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)

Answer (score 488, accepted):

The [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface (with the implementation [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) should be your friend.

The interface has the methods:

- [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#keySet--) which returns a set of the keys in ascending order
- [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#values--) which returns a collection of all values in the ascending order of the corresponding keys

So this interface fulfills exactly your requirements. However, the keys must have a meaningful order. Otherwise you can used the [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) where the order is determined by the insertion order.

Comment: example: SortedMap<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<>();

Comment: To use TreeMap it required that key class have to implement Comparable interface. If not, then some kind of RuntimeException will be thrown.
TreeMap it's also sorted map, but I think author want to use just ordered (not sorted) map. LinkedHashMap it's good choice to get only ordered map (as You said, "determined by insertion order").

Comment: `TreeMap` _does not_ require the key class to implement `Comparable` if you give it a suitable `Comparator` [during construction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap-java.util.Comparator-) (assuming you don't use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`).

Comment: this answer could be improved by showing how to iterate over keySet()

Comment: From [java 8 doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). `LinkedHashMap` whose order of iteration is the **order in which its entries were last accessed**

Comment: @TRiNE I don't follow your comment, but I may have missed some context. By default `LinkedHashMap`'s iteration order is insertion-order, but you can use a different constructor to specify access-order instead. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-

Comment: @rob yes agree.

Comment: If `SortedMap.keySet()` returns ordered keys, why not return a `List` instead of a `Set`? I can't do **anything** with the freaking set, can't even get a first element (without resorting to some weird bs loop tricks).

Comment: @parsecer: Because SortedMap is a specialication of Map, which returns a Set, since there is no order and the information that each element is unique is more valuable. You can (most likely) cast (or transform) that `Set` in a `SortedSet`, where you have a `first()` again. You can also use `SortedMap.firstKey()` for that.

Comment: OP asks about ordering, answer is about sorting

Answer (score 252):

> Is there an object that acts like a Map for storing and accessing key/value pairs, but can return an ordered list of keys and an ordered list of values, such that the key and value lists are in the same order?

You're looking for [**java.util.LinkedHashMap**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). You'll get a list of [**Map.Entry<K,V>**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) pairs, which always get iterated in the same order. That order is the same as the order by which you put the items in. Alternatively, use the [**java.util.SortedMap**](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), where the keys must either have a *natural ordering* or have it specified by a `Comparator`.

Comment: And to just save the reader double checking this, because it's hard to verify by testing, the `keySet()` method effectively returns a LinkedHashSet which reflects the order of your `put()` calls. Note that repeated calls to `put()` for the same key will not change the order unless you `remove()` the key beforehand.

Comment: @TRiNE quoting from the linked docs: "... which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map". The iteration order is always the "insertion-order", unless you use a [special constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap-int-float-boolean-) asking for "access-order"

Answer (score 43):

`LinkedHashMap` maintains the order of the keys.

`java.util.LinkedHashMap` appears to work just like a normal `HashMap` otherwise.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ianaya89 I think this is a real answer, but It's very similar to [John Feminella's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/663388/1677209) answer!

Comment: If you want to get a ordered map, where the entries are stored in that order as you put them into the map, than a LinkedHashMap is the right answer. If you want to sort the entries in your map independent form the order you put them in, than a SortedMap is the right answer.

Comment: @TRiNE The java 8 doc you linked says there are two ordering modes possible: insertion-order and access-order. You think about the latter which is invoked by the use of a special constructor public LinkedHashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor, boolean accessOrder). Default constructor creates an insertion-ordered LinkedHashMap instance.

Comment: @ArturŁysik yes it is. It was a mistake done by me days ago. I'll correct it. I'm deleting the comment. as I no longer can edit it

Answer (score 9):

## tl;dr

To keep `Map< Integer , String >` in an order sorted by key, use either of the two classes implementing the [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html)/[`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interfaces:

- [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)
- [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

… or third-party implementations. Perhaps in [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) or [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (I’ve not checked).

If manipulating the map within a single thread, use the first, `TreeMap`. If manipulating across threads, use the second, `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

For details, see the table below and the following discussion.

## Details

Here is a graphic table I made showing the features of the ten `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11.

The [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface is the successor to [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html). The `SortedMap` logically should be removed but cannot be as some 3rd-party map implementations may be using interface.

As you can see in this table, only two classes implement the `SortedMap`/`NavigableMap` interfaces:

- [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)
- [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html)

Both of these keep keys in sorted order, either by their natural order (using [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method of the `Comparable`(https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface) or by a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) implementation you pass. The difference between these two classes is that the second one, [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html), is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), highly [concurrent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing).

See also the *Iteration order* column in the table below.

- The [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) class returns its entries by the order in which they were **originally inserted**.
- [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) returns entries in the order by which the **enum class of the key is defined**. For example, a map of which employee is covering which day of the week (`Map< DayOfWeek , Person >`) uses the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum class built into Java. That enum is defined with Monday first and Sunday last. So entries in an iterator will appear in that order.

The other six implementations make no promise about the order in which they report their entries.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Comment: That diagram is a great reference - nice work, Basil!

Answer (score 7):

You can leverage [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) interface that may be accessed and traversed in either ascending or descending key order. This interface is [intended to supersede](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes6.html) the SortedMap interface. The Navigable map is usually sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time.

There are three most useful implementations of it: [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), [ImmutableSortedMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSortedMap.html), and [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

TreeMap example:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> users = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
users.put("Bob", 1);
users.put("Alice", 2);
users.put("John", 3);

for (String key: users.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(key + " (ID = "+ users.get(key) + ")");
}
```

Output:

```
Alice (ID = 2)
Bob (ID = 1)
John (ID = 3)
```

Answer (score 6):

I think the closest collection you'll get from the framework is the [SortedMap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Comment: I would down vote this answer if I thought it was worth losing the points for it. As the above answer points out, your answer lacks the proper information about LinkedHashMap, and a little explanation of SortedMap would be nice too.

Comment: @CorayThan, in that case you upvote the best answers, not downvote others that may be correct but not the best...

Comment: That's what I did. Just saying I can understand why someone would down vote it.

Answer (score 4):

I think the SortedMap interface enforces what you ask for and TreeMap implements that.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

Answer (score 4):

Since Java 6 there is also non-blocking thread-safe alternative to [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).
See [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have used **Simple Hash map, linked list and Collections** to sort a Map by values.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a simple hash map and insert some key-value pairs into it
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("Python", 3);
        map.put("C", 0);
        map.put("JavaScript", 4);
        map.put("C++", 1);
        map.put("Golang", 5);
        map.put("Java", 2);
        // Create a linked list from the above map entries
        List<Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
        // sort the linked list using Collections.sort()
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>>(){
        @Override
         public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> m1, Entry<String, Integer> m2) {
        return m1.getValue().compareTo(m2.getValue());
        }
      });
      for(Entry<String, Integer> value: list) {
         System.out.println(value);
     }
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
C=0
C++=1
Java=2
Python=3
JavaScript=4
Golang=5
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Java version of Steffi Keran's answer

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a simple hash map and insert some key-value pairs into it
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Python", 3);
        map.put("C", 0);
        map.put("JavaScript", 4);
        map.put("C++", 1);
        map.put("Golang", 5);
        map.put("Java", 2);
        // Create a linked list from the above map entries
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());
        // sort the linked list using Collections.sort()
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```