# Iterating HashMap on order it has been set

Tags: java, hashmap, iteration

I've set a HashMap on certain order but it is iterated on a strange order!

Please consider code below:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("ID", "1");
map.put("Name", "the name");
map.put("Sort", "the sort");
map.put("Type", "the type");

...

for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key + ": " + map.get(key));
}
```

and the result:

```
Name: the name
Sort: the sort
Type: the type
ID: 1
```

I need to iterate it in order i've put the entries.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try using LinkedHashMap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order

Comment: It is iterated in an *undefined* order. See the Javadoc. If you want ordering, use a Map implementation that provides it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The order depends on the result of the `hashCode()` function in the keys you are inserting which, unless you did something strange, is going to be mostly random (but consistent). What you are looking for is a sorted map such as a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Check out a little bit about how [hashtables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashmap) work here if you are interested in the details.

Answer (score 30):

That's how `HashMap` works internally. Replace `HashMap` with [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which additionally remembers the order of insertion:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
```