# Occurred order in the iteration at run-time in a map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, iterator

In the piece of code similar to

```
//something before
Iteration<String> iterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();// HashMap<String, Document>
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
//something after
```

I know that the order of print can be different by the order of insertion of entry *key, value*; all right.

But if I call this piece in another moment, with re-create the variable *hashMap* and putting them the equal elements, can the second-moment time print be different from the first-time print?

My question was born by a problem with a web-app: I have a list of **String** in a JSP, but, after some years, the customer call because the order of the **String** was different in the morning, but it shows the usual order at the afternoon.

The problem is happened in only one day: the web-app uses the explained piece of code for take a **Map** and populate an **ArrayList**.

This **ArrayList** does'nt any explicit changement of order (no *Comparator* or similar classes).

I think (hope) that the cause of different order of print derives by a different sequence of iteration in the same **HashMap** at run-time and I looking for a validation by other people.

In the web, I read that the iteration order by a **HashMap** changes if the **HashMap** receives a modification: but what happens if the **HashMap** remains the same?

Comment: Hash map document says HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: Ok, I can accept this response: can you give me a link or a source code showing this sentence, please? If you write the response I will choice your response as "best response"

Comment: Thanks.. i moved this comment to answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hash map document says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) HashMap makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

that explains though the hashmap is same it can not guaranatee on order. for Ordered map you can use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

TreeMap API says The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap API [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) states that

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 1):

For a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) that keeps its keys in **original insertion order**, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

For a `Map` that keeps its keys in **sorted order** (either natural order or by you passing a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)), use either [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html). If multi-threaded, use the second.

For a `Map` where the key an enum, use [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) if you want the entries ordered by the **definition order** of the enum's objects.

The other six `Map` implementations bundled with Java 11 do not promise any order to their entries.

See this graphic table of mine as an overview.

[image: Table of map implementations in Java 11, comparing their features]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead, to preserve insertion order. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html): "Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order."

If you just want a `Map` with predictable ordering, then you can also use `TreeMap`. However, a `LinkedHashMap` is faster, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/683524/2206044): "TreeMap has O(log n) performance for containsKey, get, put, and remove, according to the Javadocs, while LinkedHashMap is O(1) for each."

As Octopus mentioned, HashMap "makes no guarantees as to the order of the map," and you shouldn't use it if order must remain consistent.