# Is there a list implementation that would allow gaps?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for a collection that would be some sort of a list that allows gaps. The objectives are:

- every element has some index in the collection that is meaningful.
- the collection is to be sparse and not continuous; its size should return the number of proper elements, hence the workaround of initializing with `null` wouldn't work.
- `subList` method is desirable to access sublists according to index intervals

Sample use case:

```
List<Integer> list = /* ? */;
list.add(0,5);
list.add(1,4);
list.add(5,3);
for( Integer i : list )
{
    System.out.print( i + " " );
}
/* desired output : "5 4 3 "*/
```

Comment: Your requirement for the `size` method conflicts with the `List` interface. The `get` method on `List` *has* to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` of the index < 0 or > `size()`, so your `size()` method *has* to return the highest indexable element that can be retrieved with the `get()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Map<Integer,Integer>`. The key would be your index and the value the value of the list.

For your subList requirement, perhaps `TreeMap<Integer,Integer>` would work, as it keeps the keys sorted and makes it easy to iterate over a sub-list.

Of course this means you can't use the `List` interface. If you must use the `List` interface, you can make your own `List` implementation backed by a `TreeMap` (for example, `list.add(5,3)` would call `map.put(5,3)`).

Comment: Anything that implements the `NavigableMap` interface (which includes `TreeMap`) should do, as it provides the [subMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) method that satisfies the OPs need for sublists.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `Map` and only set the keys you need.

You can keep the insertion order if you want, take a look: [Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)