# List of string with occurrences count and sort

Tags: java, string, sorting, collections

I'm developing a *Java* Application that reads a lot of strings data likes this:

```
1 cat (first read)
2 dog
3 fish
4 dog
5 fish
6 dog
7 dog
8 cat
9 horse
...(last read)
```

I need a way to keep all couple [string, occurrences] **in order from last read to first read**.
**string   occurrences** 
horse     1 (first print)
 
cat          2
dog        4
fish        2 (last print)

Actually i use two list:
1) `List<string> input;` where i add all data 

In my example:

```
input.add("cat");
input.add("dog");
input.add("fish");
...
```

2)`List<string> possibilities;` where I insert the strings once in this way:

```
if(possibilities.contains("cat")){
    possibilities.remove("cat");
}
possibilities.add("cat");
```

In this way I've got a sorted list where all possibilities.
I use it like that:

```
int occurrence;
for(String possible:possibilities){
    occurrence = Collections.frequency(input, possible);
    System.out.println(possible + " " + occurrence);
}
```

That trick works good but it's too slow(i've got millions of input)... any help?
(English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.)

Comment: make a `TreeMap<String,Integer>` that will be better solution as i can think of.

Comment: A `TreeMap` will order by the string keys, not by the last read.

Comment: @RealSkeptic , i think he need manual ordering of his own way. and i got your point it can not be TreeMap

Comment: if your input is `dog,cat,dog,horse`, your desired output will be `horse,1;dog,2;cat,1` or `horse,1;cat,1;dog,1`? Please explain by editing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Map<String, Integer>`, as [@radoslaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2290235/radoslaw-grebski) pointed, to keep the insertion sorting use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) and not a `TreeMap` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order):

> `LinkedHashMap` keeps the keys in the order they were inserted, while a `TreeMap` is kept sorted via a Comparator or the natural Comparable ordering of the elements.

Imagine you have all the strings in some array, call it `listOfAllStrings`, iterate over this array and use the string as `key` in your map, if it does not exists, put in the map, if it exists, sum 1 to actual result...

```
Map<String, Integer> results = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s : listOfAllStrings) {
    if (results.get(s) != null) {
        results.put(s, results.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        results.put(s, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how is this keeping the order of the entries?

Comment: you can not do `new Map<String, Integer>();` as its interface. edit your answer make it `TreeMap`

Comment: fixed, sorry, wrote answer on the fly from my cell phone... xD

Comment: Map is an interface, you can't call new Map<>().
For keeping order use LinkedHashMap, see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: @Prashant `TreeMap` will order by the string keys, not by the last read.

Comment: LinkedHashMap and LinkedHashSet will keep order of insertion; the op is about keeping the order in last seen first-first seen last fashion.

Comment: @Revan1988 please check my edit, `LinkedHashMap` is your man ;) hope that helps

Comment: @JordiCastilla you get input `B,A,C,A`; when you update the frequency of A for the its second appearance, LinkedHashMap will _not_ reorder its keys putting A in the first position, when you reverse, you'll get `C,A,B`; from the javadoc: _Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is re-inserted into the map.(A key k is reinserted into a map m if m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)_

Comment: @JordiCastilla It's perfect!! It Works! Than you my friend!! It reduces times about 20 sec!!!

Comment: @Revan1988 Are you sure you got `horse, cat,dog,fish` rather than `horse, fish,dog,cat`?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a TreeMap, which will keep ordering on the keys as specified by the `compare` of your MyStringComparator class handling MyString class which wraps String adding insertion indexes, like this:

```
// this better be immutable
class MyString {
   private MyString() {}
   public static MyString valueOf(String s, Long l) { ... }
   private String string;
   private Long index;
   public hashcode(){ return string.hashcode(); }
   public boolean equals() { // return rely on string.equals() }
}

class MyStringComparator implements Comparator<MyString> {
   public int compare(MyString s1, MyString s2) {
       return -s1.getIndex().compareTo(s2.gtIndex()); 
  }
}
```

Pass the comparator while constructing the map:

```
Map<MyString,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(new MyStringComparator());
```

Then, while parsing your input, do

```
Long counter = 0;
while (...) {
   MyString item = MyString.valueOf(readString, counter++);
   if (map.contains(item)) {
      map.put(map.get(item)+1);
   } else {
      map.put(item,1);
   }
}
```

There will be a lot of instantiation because of the immutable class, and the comparator will not be consistent with equals, but it should work.

Disclaimer: this is untested code just to show what I'd do, I'll come back and recheck it when I get my hands on a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution for your problem,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataDto implements Comparable<DataDto>{

    public int count = 0;
    public String string;
    public long lastSeenTime;

    public DataDto(String string) {
        this.string = string;
        this.lastSeenTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if(object != null && object instanceof DataDto) {
            DataDto temp = (DataDto) object;
            if(temp.string != null && temp.string.equals(this.string)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return string.hashCode();
    }

    public int compareTo(DataDto o) {
        if(o != null) {
            return o.lastSeenTime < this.lastSeenTime ? -1 : 1; 
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.string + " : " + this.count;
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        String[] listOfAllStrings = {"horse", "cat", "dog", "fish", "cat", "fish", "dog", "cat", "horse", "fish"}; 
        Map<String, DataDto> results = new HashMap<String, DataDto>();
        for (String s : listOfAllStrings) {
            DataDto dataDto = results.get(s);
            if(dataDto != null) {
                dataDto.count = dataDto.count + 1;
                dataDto.lastSeenTime = System.nanoTime();
            } else {
                dataDto = new DataDto(s);
                results.put(s, dataDto);
            }
        }
        List<DataDto> finalResults = new ArrayList<DataDto>(results.values());
        System.out.println(finalResults);
        Collections.sort(finalResults);
        System.out.println(finalResults);
    }
}
```

Ans

```
[horse : 1, cat : 2, fish : 2, dog : 1]
[fish : 2, horse : 1, cat : 2, dog : 1]
```

I think this solution will be suitable for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your data is not going to exceed your memory capacity when you read it all into memory, then the solution is simple - using a `LinkedList` or a  and a `LinkedHashMap`.

For example, if you use a Linked list:

```
LinkedList<String> input = new LinkedList();
```

You then proceed to use `input.add()` as you did originally. But when the input list is full, you basically use Jordi Castilla's solution - but put the entries in the linked list in *reverse order*. To do that, you do:

```
    Iterator<String> iter = list.descendingIterator();
    LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String s = iter.next();
        if ( map.containsKey(s)) {
            map.put( s, map.get(s) + 1);
        } else {
            map.put(s, 1);
        }
    }
```

Now, the only real difference between his solution and mine is that I'm using `list.descendingIterator()` which is a method in `LinkedList` that gives you the entries in backwards order, from "horse" to "cat".

The `LinkedHashMap` will keep the proper order - whatever was entered first will be printed first, and because we entered things in reverse order, then whatever was read last will be printed first. So if you print your `map` the result will be:

```
{horse=1, cat=2, dog=4, fish=2}
```

---

If you have a very long file, and you can't load the entire list of strings into memory, you had better keep just the map of frequencies. In this case, in order to keep the order of entry, we'll use an object such as this:

```
private static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {

    private static long nextOrder = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    private String str;
    private int frequency = 1;
    private long order = nextOrder++;
    public Entry(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return str;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency; 
    }

    public void updateEntry() {
        frequency++;
        order = nextOrder++;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Entry e) {
        if ( order > e.order )
            return -1;
        if ( order < e.order )
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format( "%s: %d", str, frequency );
    }
}
```

The trick here is that every time you update the entry (add one to the frequency), it also updates the order. But the `compareTo()` method orders `Entry` objects from *high* order (updated/inserted later) to *low* order (updated/inserted earlier).

Now you can use a simple `HashMap<String,Entry>` to store the information as you read it (I'm assuming you are reading from some sort of scanner):

```
    Map<String,Entry> m = new HashMap<>();

    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        Entry entry = m.get(str);
        if ( entry == null ) {
            entry = new Entry(str);
            m.put(str, entry);
        } else {
            entry.updateEntry();
        }
    }

    Scanner.close();
```

Now you can sort the values of the entries:

```
    List<Entry> orderedList = new ArrayList<Entry>(m.values());
    m = null;
    Collections.sort(orderedList);
```

Running `System.out.println(orderedList)` will give you:

```
[horse: 1, cat: 2, dog: 4, fish: 2]
```

In principle, you could use a `TreeMap` whose keys contained the "order" stuff, rather than a plain `HashMap` like this followed by sorting, but I prefer not having either mutable keys in a map, nor changing the keys constantly. Here we are only changing the *values* as we fill the map, and each key is inserted into the map only once.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do:

1. Reverse the order of the list using
   [Collections.reverse(input)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)). This runs in linear time - O(n);
2. Create a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) from the input list. A Set garantees uniqueness.
   To preserve insertion order, you'll need a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html);
3. Iterate over this set, just as you did above.

Code:

```
/* I don't know what logic you use to create the input list,
 * so I'm using your input example. */
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("cat", "dog", "fish", "dog",
            "fish", "dog", "dog", "cat", "horse");
/* by the way, this changes the input list!
 * Copy it in case you need to preserve the original input. */
Collections.reverse(input);
Set<String> possibilities = new LinkedHashSet<String>(strings);

for (String s : possibilities) {
    System.out.println(s + " " + Collections.frequency(strings, s));
}
```

Output:

```
horse 1
cat 2
dog 4
fish 2
```