# why the order is not right (ascending)

Tags: java, android

i have this android code

```
HashMap<String,String> url_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        url_maps.put("Image 1", url0);
        url_maps.put("Image 2", url45);
        url_maps.put("Image 3", url90);
        url_maps.put("Image 4", url135);
        url_maps.put("Image 5", url180);
        url_maps.put("Image 6", url225);
        url_maps.put("Image 7", url270);
```

but why when it's show the order is not ascending, now the show is "3,4,1,2,7,6,5"

Comment: HashMaps make no guarantee of the order, from the JavaDocs - use LinkedHashMap or TreeMap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144776/order-of-values-retrieved-from-a-hashmap

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **LinkedHashMap** to preserve insertion order.