# Does a collection (values) from LinkedHashMap preserve the insertion order?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap, insertion-order

Let's say I have a `LinkedHashMap<String, Double> myMap` which I added `pair1`, `pair2`, `pair3` pairs to.

And now I do the following loop :

```
for (Double currDouble : myMap.getValues()) {...}
```

Would the First `Double` object in the loop be the one of `pair1`? And second of `pair2`? Or it doesn't have to be?

I checked with similar program and It seems that it does keep insertion order, but Would that always be the case?

Comment: It keeps insertion order of the **keys** (not the **values**).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!

From the first sentence of the LinkedHashMap documentation:
... implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order....  which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

If a key is reinserted ( possibly with a different value ) it doesn't change the original order.

Answer (score 3):

By default the `LinkedHashMap` preserves the insertion order. Though there is an option to switch over to access order which might have been the confusing factor.

So to answer your question, **yes**, the first `Double` will be from `pair1` and the second from `pair2` etc. Given the fact that you didn't set the `LinkedHashMap` to access order.

If you are still not sure about the behavior, you can always test it by adding a bunch of data to a `LinkedHashMap`, and iterate over it like you described in your question. You'll see that it will preserve insertion order (or access order if set).

Answer (score 0):

See [Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)

You could just do:

```
for (String key : myMap.getKeys())
  Double d = myMap.get(key);
```