# insert character in Hash Map in java.The order of the characters in the HashMab is different from the input order

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static HashMap<Character,Double> symbols = new HashMap<>();

    public static void getSymbol() {
        char ch = ' ';
        double pro;
        while (ch!='`') {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Input the character");
             ch = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (ch == '`')break;
            Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
            pro = num.nextDouble();
            symbols.put(ch, pro);

        }
        System.out.println(symbols);

    }
}
```

when I input `a,b,c,q` in this particular order
the output of `HashMap` will be : `a,q,b,c`

Comment: Use LinkedHashMap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)

Answer (score 0):

HashMap does not maintain insertion order of the elements.

Use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap implementation if you want to maintain insertion order

refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html