# Put elements into HashMap in Java

Tags: java

Why does `HashMap` returning values out of order?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put(40, "40");
        hashMap.put(10, "10");
        hashMap.put(30, "30");
        hashMap.put(20, "20");

        System.out.println(hashMap);
    }
}
```

Output:

> {20=20, 40=40, 10=10, 30=30}

I expected:

> {40=40, 10=10, 30=30, 20=20}

Comment: It is showing you the key-value relationship in a readable form. key = value

Comment: What specifically needs explaining?

Comment: It would be better if you explained what your desired output was. Its only just showing the key, value pairs that you put on your map

Comment: A Hashmap does not maintain insertion order, a LinkedHashMap will

Comment: My guess is that the OP is surprised about the _order_ in which the key-value couples are presented. I'm not sure about Java, but in Python dictionaries are not guaranteed to mantain the same insertion order. I suppose it is the same in java.

Comment: @DaveNewton about order

Comment: See [Java class that implements Map and keeps insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order) for more info on other maps that maintain ordering.  HashMap in particular says this on its javadoc page: "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: Here's another tutorial of information regarding the difference between the forms of Maps in Java:
[HashMap vs TreeMap vs HashTable vs LinkedHashMap](https://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs-hashtable-vs-linkedhashmap/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `HashHap` is unordered. So there is no particular order in which the key value pairs will be represented by `toString()`.

The `toString()` method of `HashMap`, which is called by `System.out.println`, is implemented to represent the map as String like this:

```
{key0=value0, key1=value1,..., keyN=valueN}
```

The order can but is not guaranteed to to be the order of insertion.

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of the map interface that you are using here (HashMap) does not maintain the order of insertion. You need to use something like LinkedHashMap or TreeMap.
Hopefully this answer will help you more
[Java Class that implements Map and keeps insertion order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683518/java-class-that-implements-map-and-keeps-insertion-order)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the toString method from the hashmap, not actually getting the values, you should get the values using get

```
hashMap.get(10);
```