# Function clash when implementing multiple interfaces

Tags: java

I have a variant-style object `foo` that is capable of behaving as a `java.util.Map` and a `java.util.List` as well as other plain-old-data types. This object is written in C++ (modelled on the *composite pattern*) and I'm building a JNI so that I can use it in Java.

In Java, I'm motivated to write

```
public class foo implements 
        Streamable, 
        java.util.Map<String, foo>,
        java.util.List<foo>
```

Then I encounter trouble. For example, I need to implement 3 flavors of `remove`:

```
public foo remove(int index)   
public boolean remove(Object key)   
public foo remove(Object key)
```

The first two are for `java.util.list`, the final one for `java.util.map`. This, of course, is a problem since you cannot have two functions with the same name and parameters but *different* return types.

Is there a way round this?

Comment: Can't you use composition here. This really sounds weird.

Comment: Bad! One class. One responsibility. Your code needs refactoring :-/

Comment: @AmitSharma: not entirely; composite pattern is well established. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Comment: Will your single instance of `foo` be consumed as a Stream, Map, and List simultaneously?

Comment: The Map and List are orthogonal. Stream is simultaneous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An adapter would work. Have one class implement `Map` and `Stream`, and another class implement `List` and `Stream`. All operations required by these adapter's respective interfaces would draw from a common underlying foo instance.

Comment: Yes this is probably the best you can do given that my idea, on reflection, is fundamentally illogical. So +1 and accept.

Comment: Could someone explain the -1 here? Also, @Bathsheba, I would recommend you refactor so `foo` doesn't implement these drastically different interfaces. I understand you're following a composite design pattern, but when the interface's behavior are so fundamentally different, I advise against it. Instead, try creating 3 separate adapters implementing Stream, list, and map, backed by the same data source. I'd be interested in your reasoning in implementing Map, and Stream on one object if you'd care to elaborate.

Comment: In the end I went for coercion methods like `asList()` and `asMap()` which return concrete standard java types. They fitted quite well with other methods like `asString()` and `asDouble()` which I already had. Your answer certainly put me on the right track.

Comment: Ah, great, I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218602/implement-both-map-and-list-interface-in-java) as it discusses the same problem you're having.

Comment: That's a nice class. But my problem is that the implementation is all in C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba, so I would ask you to please update your post... This is not what you said there. :/

Comment: I clearly say the object is written in C++ and I'm building a JNI around it.