# Java data structure sorted by key

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to store integers in a data structure with a String as the key,
an example of what im storing is:

```
key: "Name1", Int: 123
key: "Name2", Int: 124
```

I want to be able to insert entries so that they are ordered alphabetically for purposes of easy printing to screen.

So far ive been using:

```
Dictionary<String,Integer> x = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
x.put("Name1",123);
x.put("Name2",124);

Enumeration<String> e;
String key;
for(e=x.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();){
    key=e.nextElement();
    System.out.println(key + ": " + x.get(key));
}
```

This Outputs:

```
Name2: 124
Name1: 123
```

Why aren't these in alphabetical order?
Is there an alternative to Dictionary that I should know about?

Comment: You're looking for a [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Ordered Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless otherwise stated, maps/hashmaps/hashtables/dictionaries/etc. don't have *any* defined sort ordering. A [`TreeMap<String, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) should work for your purposes; it implements the [`SortedMap<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface.

That said, I'm not necessarily convinced you should be picking a data structure just because it makes *printing* easier.

---

Side note: `Dictionary` and `Hashtable` are legacy classes which exist primarily for backwards compatibility. New code should generally prefer [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) for general-purpose key-value data structures.

Comment: You should mention the `SortedMap` and `NavigableMap` interfaces, which _do_ specify an ordering.

Comment: Printing isnt the only reason, i need it to overwrite duplicate entries too, im fairly sure most of the maps do that though

Comment: @clairharrison correct - any correct implementation of `Map` will prohibit duplicate keys.