# Data structure that has key-value mapping as well as ordering

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

I need a data structure that provides key-value mappings, like a `Map`, but that also allows me to fetch the key based on an (int) index (e.g. `myKey = myDS.get(index)`), without having to iterate over the data structure to get the key at the desired index.

I thought of using `LinkedHashMap`, but I don't see a way to get the key at a given index. Am I missing something in `LinkedHashMap`? Or is there another data structure I can use?

**EDIT**:
 
This is **not** a duplicate.  The correct answer to the other question is to use some sort of `SortedMap`; however, that is **not** the correct answer to this question, since I'd like to be able to retrieve an `Entry` from the data structure via an `Integer` index, which is not supported in any Java library.

Comment: Do you need any specific ordering? That is -- do you need any coherent mapping from indices to keys?

Comment: I just need ordering to be preserve, like if i entered element element first time, it should always be available at index 0, for second element index should be 1 and so on...

Comment: please refer to this answer on stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/a/663396/611077

Comment: @ruakh: My question is very different from the one you suggested. In the suggested question, that person is getting the `values` from the `list` based on index of `map`, whereas i need to get `key` from the `map` based on index and this `key` is not a list. Also, i am open for any data structure suggestion, but in suggested question workaround is asked when `map` is used... So i these two questions are very different from each other

Comment: @KanishkaGupta: I think you've confused me with [arknave](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1544606/arknave). All I asked is whether you need any specific ordering.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This satisfy key-value property but when it comes to fetching key based on index of key, then i am not sure how to proceed. Could you please share information how will i find key when an integer index is given to me

Comment: @ruakh Ohh sorry!! that's mistake from my side and i apologize. Yes that comment was for aknave

Comment: Do you need to support removal?

Comment: I need to clear the data structure, and refill it. So i think instead of using remove() of particular element i will be needing to clear() or i will make myDS = null;

Comment: @KanishkaGupta My answer should eliminate your confusion **and** provide you with the required data structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) provides a hash table/doubly linked list implementation of the `Map` interface.  Since it `extends HashMap`, it's still backed by an array, but there is also a doubly-linked list of `Entry` objects to ensure that the iteration order is predictable.

So, basically what it means is that when you iterate through the map like so:

```
for (Map.Entry<keyType,valueType>> entry : linkedHashMap.entrySet())
{
   System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey().toString() + 
                     " Value: " + entry.getValue.toString());
}
```

it will print in the order that you added the keys, as opposed to a non-linked Map, which will **not** print in *insertion order*.  You **cannot** access the elements of the array  like you want to, because the array that backs the hash is not in *order*.  Only the doubly linked list is ordered.

## Solution:

What you are looking for is a [LinkedMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/LinkedMap.html) from Apache Commons.

Comment: @Neel Yes, it's a cool data structure.  Not really sure why Java doesn't have something comparable.

Comment: Only 2 questions come to my mind: 1. What if I am not allowed to use a third party library like the commons API's? 2. Why do I need a single data structure to do both to begin with?

Comment: Probably because Java does not want to clutter ts util API's to accommodate every use case possible while it actually provides for few of the most fundamental ones :)

Comment: @Neel Yeah, that's probably true...(1) You could write your own, that's what my roommate had to do for a project that he was working on. (2) Is a much more complicated answer.  This isn't what you're looking for, but basically if you want to be able to reap the benefits of a `HashMap`, while also reaping the benefits of an array.  The reason he needed it was very complex.  Off the top of my head, I can't think of a simple reason, but I'm sure many exist.  Sorry for the crappy (2) answer.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no single data structure that will do this.  There is certainly not one in the standard Java collection suite.

Also `LinkedHashMap` is not the solution because you cannot efficiently index a `LinkedHashMap`.

If you want to do index-based lookup as well as keep-based lookup, solution needs to be a combination of two data structures.

- A `Map<Key, Value>` and an `ArrayList<Value>` is the simpler approach, but it has a couple of problems:
      - Insertion and deletion of values from the `ArrayList` is expensive, unless you are inserting / deleting at the tail end of the list.
      - Insertion and deletion makes the list positions unstable,.
- If you want stable indexes and scalable insertion and deletion, then you need a `Map<Key, Value>` and a `Map<Integer, Value>` ... and a way to manage (i.e. recycle) the index values.

---

The Apache Commons `LinkedMap` class is a possible solution, except that it suffers from the problem that index values are not stable in the face of insertions and deletions.

Comment: There is in the Apache Commons library, see my answer.  No java library exists to my knowledge, though.  Interesting idea with the two `Maps`.

Comment: Based on the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/AbstractLinkedMap.java#AbstractLinkedMap.addEntry%28org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap.HashEntry%2Cint%29), I don't see why the index values are not stable in the face of insertions and deletions.  Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

How about using:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
List<Entry<String, String>> mapAsList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,String>>(map.entrySet());

 mapAsList.get(index);
```

Comment: I am not sure how it will work. It seems bit complex, but i will need to check what Entry<> actually does.

Comment: An [Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a composition of <Key,Value>

Comment: I think get() expects the `key` and i am unable to get point how can i make `key` work as `index` for map and how List data structure here is helping me, since i am operating on calling get() on map and not operating on List

Comment: @KanishkaGupta See my answer, it may help to solve your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a collection for this; collections are *either* based on the idea that you want to know exactly where an element is (lists) *or* that you want quick access based on some key or criteria (maps); doing both would be very resource-intensive to maintain.

Of course, you can make something like this, as rocketboy's answer suggests, but I'm guessing it's not really possible to make efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct DS in the standard Java Collections API to provide a indexed map. However, the following should let you achieve the result:

```
// An ordered map
Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
// To create indexed list, copy the references into an ArrayList (backed by an array)
List<Entry<K, V>> indexedList = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());
// Get the i'th term
<Map.Entry<K,V>> entry = indexedList.get(index);
K key = entry.getKey();
V value = entry.getValue();
```

You might still want to retain the concerns of data persistence in the map separate from the retrieval.

Update:
Or use LinkedMap from Apache Commons as suggested by Steve.