# How to make a query in mongo (mongo template) that it returns a result without alterations?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

I have only one document in my mongoDB. This is:

```
{
"_id": "32fqwefr",
"propertyName": "configShowableField",
"Applicant": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
],
"Employment": [
    "R:a_FIIq",
    "R:a_PsN"
],
"Product": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
],
"Address": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
]
}
```

and returns that document.

I've made a query to get it

```
Map<String, List<String>> configShowable = new HasMapsh<>();
Query query = new Query();
query.addCirteria(Criteria.where("propertyName").is("configShowableField"));
Map<String. Object> config = getMongoTemplate.findOne(query, Map.class,"Collection");
config.forEach(k,v)->{
if(v instanceof List){
    configShowable.put(k, (List<String>V));
}
}
return configShowable;
```

The problem is that the `configShowable` order is altered and I do not need that. I need that I return the same in which was inserted in the data base, in orther words, the Map than was created is in disoreder.

Exmaple:

```
{
"_id": "32fqwefr",
"propertyName": "configShowableField",
"Address": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
],
"Applicant": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
],
"Product": [
    "R:a_FII",
    "R:a_PN"
],
"Employment": [
    "R:a_FIIq",
    "R:a_PsN"
]
}
```

How can I prevent that disorder??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Ordered Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map)

Comment: Are you sure the document has the structure you want in mongodb? When you insert it, mongodb should sort it in alphabetical order and ruin your plans long before you ask for a result.

Comment: @Digits I am sure of that because I've added it manualy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use LinkedHaskMap , keeps the keys in the order they were inserted