# Java Hashmap: Keys not ordered accordingly after printing the values of the map

Tags: java, hashmap

i wrote a small java program that uses Hashmap. The program prompts to enter 3 employee names with its salary. After entering the 3 employees with salaries, I just want to simply output the map key and values in the console. However, I have observed that the output is not ordered the same way as I input.

**Sample input**

Enter employee name 1:> Dara

Enter salary for Dara:> 200

Enter employee name 2:> Logan

Enter salary for Logan:> 300

Enter employee name 3:> Agnes

Enter salary for Logan:> 300

**Output looks like this:**

Agnes  > 300.0

Logan >  300.0

Dara   > 200.0

Observe that Dara is now placed at the bottom and Agnes is on top. It should be the other way around as how I input it. Please see my code below.

public class Maps {

```
static String name = "";
static double salary = 0;
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<String, Double>();


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Maps ms = new Maps();

    int count = 1;

    while(count <= 3){
        System.out.println("Enter employee " + count);
        name = sc.next();

        System.out.println("------------------");

        System.out.println("Enter salary for " + name);
        salary = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("\n");

        m.put(name, salary);

        count += 1;


    }

    ms.displayMap();


}

public void displayMap(){

    System.out.println("========================");

    **I think the issue lies in here**
    for(Entry<String, Double> employee : m.entrySet()){
        String key = employee.getKey();
        Double value = employee.getValue();

        System.out.println(key + " \t " + value);
    }







}
```

}

Comment: `HashMap` is not ordered. Try using a [TreeMap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/663396/4622673).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Ordered Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map)

Comment: Try reading a JavaDoc for HashMap class first. It is all there - why spend time and posting on SO if you have documentation right there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `LinkedHashMap`if you want to keep the elements in same order in which they were inserted.

[LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

Comment: Please check for duplicate question, there is already complete answers about this subject

Answer (score 0):

Hash Map does not guarantee order. Please refer the below link.

[Java 8 Hash Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This
>   implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and
>   permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly
>   equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits
>   nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

Comment: Please check for duplicate question, there is already complete answers about this subject

Answer (score 0):

Use [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) or [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

I suggest a LinkedHashMap or a TreeMap. A LinkedHashMap keeps the keys in the order they were inserted, while a TreeMap is kept sorted via a Comparator or the natural Comparable ordering of the elements.

Since it doesn't have to keep the elements sorted, LinkedHashMap should be faster for most cases; TreeMap has O(log n) performance for containsKey, get, put, and remove, according to the Javadocs, while LinkedHashMap is O(1) for each.