# Items order isn't the same as property file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I use properties file to load drop-down options in Spring MVC form.

#### Why the order of options in the drop-down component does not correspond to the order in the property file?

#### property file:

```
BR=Brazil 
FR=France 
CO=Colombia 
IN=India
```

#### UI:

```
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
    <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
</select>
```

### Additional info:

#### spring config file:

```
<util:properties id="countryOptions" location="classpath:../countries.properties" />
```

#### Injection in Controller:

```
@Value("#{countryOptions}")
private Map<String, String> countryOptions;
```

#### form jsp code:

```
Country:

<form:select path="country">
     <form:options items="${theCountryOptions}" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: Because `countryOptions` is a `Map` which has no order by default.

Comment: What is the best approach to make the order identical?

Comment: Instead of accessing the field, create a method returning a (ordered) `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>` accessed via the JSP.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try `LinkedHashMap<String, String> countryOptions;` instead of `Map`

Comment: Question that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map