# Merge two maps in specific order

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have two Maps map1 and map2. I want to combine both these Maps in specific order.
Assume I have two maps

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("id1", "3895");
map1.put("id2", "6754");
map1.put("id3", "7896");
map1.put("id4", "1122");

map2.put("month1", "Jan");
map2.put("month2", "Mar");
map2.put("month3", "Dec");
map2.put("month4", "Aug");
```

Now I want to combine these two maps so that the third map will have elements in below order.
Expected order in Map3.

```
("id1", "3895")
("month1", "Jan")
("id2", "6754")
("month2", "Mar")
("id3", "7896")
("month3", "Dec")
("id4", "1122")
("month4", "Aug")
```

How do I achieve this? I tried with putAll and LinkedHashMap but the resulting order is not the expected one.

With LinkedHashMap -

```
Map<String, String> merged = Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

and the result is

```
("id1", "3895")
("id2", "6754")
("id3", "7896")
("id4", "1122")
("month1", "Jan")
("month2", "Mar")
("month3", "Dec")
("month4", "Aug")
```

which is not my expected one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Ordered Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map)

Comment: [This one might also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/683518/1270789) answer your question.

Comment: You don't say what type of `Map` you used for the third map, but a `HashMap` won't work because `HashMap`s  have no order.  You should be able to achieve what you want by using a `LinkedHashMap` (which maintains entries in insertion order) and inserting the items individually in the desired order.

Comment: does the both maps always have same number of keys?

Comment: @KenY-N No both info that you shared doesn't help me. I was looking for merging two maps in specific order.

Comment: @deadshot yes both have same number of keys

Comment: @Nicolas Since the two maps you currently have are `HashMap` objects, which are **unordered** maps, merging them in *specific order* makes no sense at all.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I know how to order individual map but I was looking for merging two maps into one in above specific order.

Comment: Have you tried iterating them both in parallel and adding entries to a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), i.e. a map that maintains **insertion order**?

Comment: @Andreas can you share the code for that?

Comment: @Nicolas Can you make an attempt yourself? StackOverflow is not a write-my-code-for-me site. Which part of what I said do you find too hard to overcome by yourself, even with the help of web searches?

Comment: @Andreas if I had the solution I wouldn't have posted the question here. I already tried with LinkedHashMap but the result I got is map2 is appended map1. i.e .  
 ("id1", "3895")
("id2", "6754")
("id3", "7896")
("id4", "1122")
("month1", "Jan")
("month2", "Mar")
("month3", "Dec")
("month4", "Aug")

Comment: *" I already tried with LinkedHashMap"* --- Then **edit** the question and show what you tried, so we might help you figure out what you did wrong. Though from what you showed, you **didn't iterate** the two input maps **in parallel**, i.e. at the same time, like I said you should. You did read what I said, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Andreas, you can iterate over maps in parallel and to `LinkedHashMap` to maintain order,

```
Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter1 = map1.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iter2 = map2.entrySet().iterator();
while(iter1.hasNext() || iter2.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, String> e1 = iter1.next();
    Map.Entry<String, String> e2 = iter2.next();

    result.put(e1.getKey(), e1.getValue());
    result.put(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue());

}
```

If keys of both the maps are like id1, id2, month1, month2, then you can use a custom `Comparator` with number for sort as below,

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(c -> c.getKey().replaceAll("^\\D+", ""))  ;
Map<String, String> collect = Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
        .sorted(comparator)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Code_Mode, it really helped :)

Comment: Your first code will fail when using two maps with different sizes. Further, it can’t change the fact that the `HashMap`s of the question’s code do not have a defined iteration order to begin with. So it doesn’t help that the resulting `LinkedHashMap` will remember that unspecified order.

Comment: OP confirmed that both the maps have the same number of keys. But I agree with your second point.

Answer (score -1):

To merge (interleave) the content of two maps, iterate them both in parallel and add to a `LinkedHashMap`, so the insertion order is retained.

1. Create `mergedMap` as a `LinkedHashMap`
2. Get `iterator1` as an iterator for the *entries* of `map1`
3. Get `iterator2` as an iterator for the *entries* of `map2`
4. Repeat until both iterators are at-end:

   5. If not at-end, get next entry from `iterator1` and add to `mergedMap`.
   6. If not at-end, get next entry from `iterator2` and add to `mergedMap`.

That's it. That's all there is to it. Now you just need to write the code doing that.