# How to prevent HashSet to change my array order that i assign from List?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, hashset

What i trying to achieve is my Set having the same order as my List which is chaging when i assign value from List to Set. Here is what i do :

```
// in here my array still showing same as my submited front end
List<ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto> submitedShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto = shipmentAddressGroupingDto.getShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto();

//in here my array start changing, it's not the same order again as my object above
        Set<ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto> setShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto = new HashSet(submitedShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto);
        List<ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto> shipmentAddressGroupingDtDto = new ArrayList<ShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto>(setShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto);
```

here is my value for submitedShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto :

```
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 1
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 2
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 4
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjolx",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 7
      ]
```

and what i saw in debug mode, in my **setShipmentAddressGroupingDtDto** is like this :

```
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 2
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjolx",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 7
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 1
      ],
      [
        "id": 0,
        "address": "Jl. Imam Bonjol",
        "isActive": true,
        "partnerShipmentId": 4
      ]
```

How do i prevent Set ordering my List? or if i can't prevent that, how can i sort it as my submited value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Ordered Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663374/java-ordered-map) (the tiny bit about `LinkedHashMap` at the end of the selected answer, at least)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes yes, exactly it worked! i just try it, it didn't change my order anymore, you want to put your comment as the answer?

Comment: Great to hear that :) But since it's a duplicate there's no need to add an answer.

Comment: ohh okay i will delete my question in a sec, thank u brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [LinkedHashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) which maintains the ordering of the elements you put into it.

Comment: oh sorry i going to accept your answer even it's a duplicate, the question bit different, hope someone find a same mistake can come here, thank you